# Find and Replace specific string in Outlook message

Tags: vba, outlook

My code basically searches for the string `"#XX"` in the email body. The `"#XX"` is usually followed by a text like `"#XXApple"`. And this `"#XXApple"` can be seen multiple times in the email message.

The code below works in such a way that it only replaces the first hit with spaces. However, the rest of the `"#XXApple"` will only be changed to `"Apple"`

Is there a way where I can do a "Find and Replace All" in Outlook?

```
obj.HTMLBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, "#XX", " ", 15)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to first find whether `#XX` is start of any string and if it is then you want to replace the full string rather than just `#XX` ?
E.g. Input `#XXApple` , `#XXBanana` and Output is the whole string replaced with something else

Comment: @Rohan K Yes something like that. Or another is to delete the whole string "#XXApple"

Comment: okay what you can do is take the whole email body in one string and then [Split](http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_split_function.html) the string by spaces and test each splitted string for a match using [Instr](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Instr&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=QwCrVuv_GoSOuATupZyACg#q=Instr+vba) and if there is match then replace that string with `""`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested or verified but this is the general idea of what I meant to say in the comment above.

```
 Dim Cet
 Dim TesPos As Int, i As Int
 Cet = Split(obj.HTMLBody, " ")

 For i=LBound(Cet) to Ubound(Cet)
     TestPos = 5
     TestPos = InStr(1,Cet(i), "#XX", CompareMethod.Text)

     if TestPos = 1 then
         Cet(i) = ""
     Else: End if
 Next i

 obj.HTMLBody = ""
 For i=LBound(Cet) to Ubound(Cet)
    obj.HTMLBody = obj.HTMLBody & " " & Cet(i)
 Next i

 Debug.Print obj.HTMLBody
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to deal with the message body. But the Word object model provides all the required methods to get the job done.